# maxConnection setting being ignored on .NET 4 client

Tags: .net, multithreading, system.net

I have .NET 4 code (not ASP) running both on win 7 and server 2008 that creates multiple threads (each with a webclient, as I need separate cookiecontainers) for requests and responses to websites.

I use multiple proxies and for each proxy I will have a number of different user-agents strings, so each thread will be opening a connection based on proxy + user-agent.  i.e.: 10 Proxy’s x 8 UA strings = 80 connections on 80 threads. [I do believe Async would be a better choice, although I do need separate web-clients]

In order not to overwhelm website with requests I want to rely on .NET internal pipe-lining to prevent more than one parallel request at once to same endpoint. i.e. I added this in my config file:

```
<connectionManagement>
<add address="*" maxconnection="1" />
</connectionManagement>
```

Yet my logs show that it is being ignored and all 8 connections to same endpoint are being created more or less simultaneously. Is this happening because each connection is being made on a separate thread? And if yes, any other setting for it to work per process besides having my code limit multiple simultaneous connections to same endpoint?

**EDIT**

As per request, idea of Code that launches each request:

```
Public Class cWebClient
    Inherits WebClient

    Public Property URL As String

    ......
    Public Sub GetUrl()
        .......
        Dim html As String = Me.DownloadString(u)
        .......
End Class
```

Code that creates each different class

```
Sub LaunchThreads()
Dim wc as new cWebClient
.....
Dim ts As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf wc.GetURL)
```

Comment: Just a note: Your XML is not valid

Comment: I don't know the answer but using `SemaphoreSlim` is a quick fix that gives you more control. No need for global settings. Just turn them off.

Comment: Please provide more information, show relevant code and tell us please what technology do you use to perform server-client operations. Is it WCF?